# JavaScript no redirect on post

Tags: javascript, url, post, attributes

I was looking at this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit), and i was wondering, is there a way to make this function work as it should but without redirecting to a different page?

```
function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

My problem is on this  line `form.setAttribute("action", path);` which sent's to a different site

Comment: Simply make an AJAX call that's sending the form data.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#post

Comment: Okay i  see thank. one last thing is there any difference between any of them

Comment: Learn how AJAX works, and it will all get clear. Basically, it's an asynchronous call (it happens 'behind' the page), but you can wait for its response and modify your page accordingly based on that response. There's much more to it, but this will get you started. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX

Comment: Thanks a lot, you solved my problem, if you want you can post it as an answer so i can accept

Comment: You're welcome, man. I'm not sure if it's going to help anyone else (if not, you should probably delete the whole question), but I've posted it as an answer. If you decide it's not going to help someone else, feel free to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to send the request. With jQuery it can look like this.

```
$.post( "test.php", $( "#testform" ).serialize() );
```

Comment: Your answer's a bit short. Also, linking to an external site is discouraged in answers due to the fact that that link might break at some time in the future. Please expand your answer with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing it within comments, here is the answer version.

Instead of using a form, you need to make an AJAX call that's sending the form data.
Learn how AJAX works, and it will all get clear. Basically, it's an asynchronous call (it happens 'behind' the page), but the good thing is that you can wait for its response and modify your page accordingly based on that response (for example, showing a 'thank you' message, or an error, etc...).

There's much more to it, but this will get you started. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX

Also, there are millions of examples and tutorials online, so you won't have any problem doing it now that you know what you need to do.

Answer (score -1):

I think iframes may help you. Tryout:)